# Is it possible to @CacheEvict keys that match a pattern?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-cache

Is there something along the lines of `@CacheEvict(value = "FOO", key = "baz*")` so that when the cache `FOO` contains keys `baz_1` and `baz_2` they get evicted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming** that you have `spring-boot-starter-cache` as dependency, spring boot auto-configures a `CacheManager` bean named `cacheManager`.

Also, **assuming** you have `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` as a dependency, `RedisCacheManager` is picked as the `CacheManager` implementation.

`@CacheEvict` (and the caching abstraction API) doesn't let you the option to evict by prefix, but using an AOP advice (or elsewhere where fits), you can take advantage of the underlying implementation:

```
    RedisCache redisCache = (RedisCache) cacheManager.getCache("FOO");
    redisCache.getNativeCache().clean("FOO",  "baz*".getBytes());
```

Didn't try it actually, but I think this should work.

Likewise, you can adapt to other caching implementation.

The shortcoming of this approach, is that you'll have to change your code upon changing the cache implementation.

Comment: Your assumptions were right. It worked. Thank you! :)