# Implement "cache tags pattern" in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-cache

I have been searching for long time in the Internet, if Spring supports the "cache tag pattern" but seems it doesn't.... How do you implement this cache pattern in Spring???

An example of this cache pattern can be seen in Drupal cache tag implementation, I will create an example of how would that look

```java
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
class TicketService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final ProductRepository productRepository;
    private final TicketRepository ticketRepository;

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "global-tags-cache", tags = { "ticket:list", "user:#{user.id}", "product:#{product.id}"})
    public List<TicketDto> findTicketsForUserThatIncludesProduct(User user, Product product) {
           var tickets = ticketRepository.findByUserAndProduct(user, product);
    }

    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "global-tags-cache", tags = "ticket:list")
    public Ticket saveNewTicket(TicketRequestDto ticketRequestDto) { ... }

}

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
class ProductService {
    private final ProductRepository productRepository;

    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "global-tags-cache", tags = "product:#{productRequestDto.id}")
    public Product updateProductInformation(ProductRequestDto productRequestDto() { 
        ... 
    }
}

@Service
class NonTagCacheService() {
   @Cacheable(cacheNames = "some-non-global-cache-store")
   public Object doStrongComputation() { ... }
}
```

The idea is to handle the responsability of the "tag eviction" where it belongs to, for example TicketService wants its cache to be break when user is altered, **or** when any ticket is altered, **or** when the specified product is altered... TicketService doesn't need to know when or where Product is going to clear its tag

This pattern is strongly useful in Drupal, and makes its cache very powerfull, this is just an example, but one can implement its own tags for whatever reason he wants, for example a "kafka-process:custom-id"

Comment: No. Nor is there any cache in Java that supports this. You would (or could) mimic this with your own cache key implementation an cache key creator. However the sample you show doesn't even operate on the same cache so not sure how useful that would be.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum I have updated the question to better mimic Drupal's behavior, so when the cache is about tags, the used store ("cache name") is the same for all... while objects that don't rely on tags may be stored elsewhere

Comment: One thing you have to keep in mind that the Drupal one is written for a specific usecase. The Spring Cache API is an **abstraction** over all different cache providers, and thus provides an API covering the main features. If there is a Cache API that provides this, it doesn'tmean it is in the Spring Cache API. But as stated I'm not aware of such an implementation that has this support in the java scope. Mainly because most implementations use the Java Caching API and provide an implementation, which doesn't cover that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) explained, [Spring's Cache Abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-strategies) is just that, an "*abstraction*", or rather an SPI enabling different *caching providers* to be plugged into the framework in order to offer caching capabilities to managed application services (beans) where needed, not unlike Security, or other cross-cutting concerns.

Spring's Cache Abstraction only declares fundamental, but essential caching functions that are common across most *caching providers*. In effect, Spring's Cache Abstraction implements the lowest common denominator of caching capabilities (e.g. `put` and `get`). You can think of `java.util.Map` as the most basic, fundamental cache implementation possible, and is indeed [one](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-store-configuration-jdk) of the many supported *caching providers* offered out of the box (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-store-configuration) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.caching.provider)).

This means advanced caching functions, such as expiration, eviction, compression, serialization, general memory management and configuration, and so on, are left to individual providers since these type of capabilities vary greatly from one cache implementation (provider) to another, as does the configuration of these features. This would be no different in **Drupal's** case.  The framework [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-specific-config) is definitive on this matter.

Still, not all is lost, but it usually requires a bit of work on the users part.

Being that the [`Cache`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html) and [`CacheManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html) interfaces are the primary interfaces (SPI) of the Spring Cache Abstraction, it is easy to extend or customize the framework.

First, and again, as [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) points out, you have the option of [custom key generation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-key). But, this offers no relief with respect to (custom) eviction policies based on the key(s) (or tags applied to cache entries).

Next, you do have the option to get access to the low-level, "native" cache implementation of the provider using the API, [`Cache.getNativeCache()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html#getNativeCache--).  Of course, then you must forgo the use of [Spring Cache Annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations), or alternatively, the [JCAche API Annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-jsr-107), supported by Spring, which isn't as convenient, particularly if you want to enable/disable caching conditionally.

Finally, I tested a hypothesis to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69829332/is-it-possible-to-cacheevict-keys-that-match-a-pattern) posted in SO not long ago regarding a similar problem... using Regular Expressions (REGEX) to evict entries in a cache where the keys matched the REGEX.  I never provided an answer to this question, but I did come up with a ["generic" solution](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithRegexIntegrationTests.java), implemented with 3 different caching providers: [Redis](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithRegexIntegrationTests.java#L280-L367), [Apache Geode](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithRegexIntegrationTests.java#L369-L407), and using the [simple ConcurrentMap implementation](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithRegexIntegrationTests.java#L273-L278).

This involved a significant amount of supporting infrastructure classes, beginning [here](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithRegexIntegrationTests.java#L409-L656) and declared [here](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithRegexIntegrationTests.java#L255-L265).  Of course, my goal was to implement support for multiple *caching providers* via "*decoration*".  Your implementation need not be so complicated, or rather sophisticated, ;-)

Part of my future work on the Spring team will involve gathering use cases like yours and providing (pluggable) extensions to the core Spring Framework Cache Abstraction that may eventually find its way back into the core framework, or perhaps exist as separate pluggable modules based on application use case and requirements that our many users have expressed over the years.

At any rate, I hope this offers you some inspiration on how to possibly and more elegantly handle your use case.

Always keep in mind the Spring Framework is an exceptional example of the [*Open/Closed* principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle); it offers many extension points, and when combined with the right design pattern (e.g. [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), not unlike AOP itself), it can be quite powerful.

Good luck!

Comment: I did my own implementation, https://github.com/KevinGuancheDarias/taggable-cache , but it is not integrated in any way with the existing Spring Cache module... with your provided code example, I may in the future replace my own implemented cache manager and use Spring's one, for underlying cache management of my custom annotations. For now I'm happy with the ConcurrentHashMap, in the future I may need Redis, and will for sure come back here, and look at your repo. I added this to the README.

Big thanks!

Comment: You are most welcome.