# Spring Cache: Evict hierarchical entries

Tags: spring, spring-cache

Using Spring Cache, I want to store in the cache the return value of a function with two parameters, but evict entries using only the first one, ignoring the second... a kind of hierarchical eviction.

Example:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "myCache", cacheManager = "myCacheManager")
public String foo(Long id, String subId)
```

```
foo(1,"A");
foo(1,"B");`
foo(1,"C");
--
foo(2,"A");
foo(2,"B");
```

```
fooEvict(1); // Should evict all entries where id=1
```

```
@CacheEvict(cacheNames = "myCache", cacheManager = "myCacheManager")
public void fooEvict(Long id) {
     LOG.debug("Should evict all entries where id= {} ", id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eviction algorithms are specific to *caching provider* and the capabilities vary widely from 1 caching provider to the next. It is also the reason Spring [explicitly states](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-specific-config) Eviction (and Expiration) are not generally concerns handled by the framework itself given these concerns are implementation dependent.

Having said that, your mileage will vary depending on the *caching provider* you chose from the onset. For example, if you are using **Redis**, then it is possible to use **Redis's** API direcctly to accomplish a similar Eviction strategy using REGEX, which I actually saw from [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69829332/is-it-possible-to-cacheevict-keys-that-match-a-pattern).

I was actually inspired by the question and took it upon myself to build a more [generic solution](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithRegexIntegrationTests.java) to this problem that works with different caching providers under the hood.

In my [test class](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithRegexIntegrationTests.java) (prototype), I tested 3 different caching provider implementations.

The [first configuration](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithRegexIntegrationTests.java#L273-L278), since my test is a Spring Boot test, just uses the [default, "simple" caching provider implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.caching.provider.simple), which is a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

The [second configuration](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithRegexIntegrationTests.java#L280-L367) uses **Redis**, and as you can [see](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithRegexIntegrationTests.java#L319), it employs the technique from the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69829332/is-it-possible-to-cacheevict-keys-that-match-a-pattern) I shared above.

The [final configuration](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithRegexIntegrationTests.java#L369-L407) uses [Apache Geode](https://geode.apache.org/), an in-memory, distributed data store, like Hazelcast, that I am most familiar with, which can be [used as *caching provider*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#geode-caching-provider) in *Spring's Cache Abstraction*.

The rest of the [code below](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithRegexIntegrationTests.java#L409-L656) is supporting infrastructure classes to make the generic solution possible across different *caching providers*.

In time, I plan to port this code to a [new library](https://github.com/codeprimate-software/cp-extensions/tree/master/spring-extensions) that I am currently building that includes extensions for many things in Spring, including caching, which is my area of expertise at VMware.

The approach used in my test might be overkill for your UC. If so, then you can simply implement Spring's 2 primary interfaces in the *Cache Abstraction* responsible for caching behavior in the framework, the [`Cache`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html) and [`CacheManger`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html) interfaces.

You can do so using the `Adapter` design pattern to wrap an existing *caching provider* implementation with the extended Eviction functionality you require.

Of course, there are many other ways to solve this problem, and hopefully this helps spur some ideas of your own.

If you have more questions, feel free to post in the comments below.

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer. I am using Caffeine cache and thanks of your feedback, I found a way doing this with Caffeine. Cheers.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Wishing you success.