# Evict cache for multiple keys rather than all in Spring Redis

Tags: spring-data-redis, spring-cache, redis-cache

Is there any way we can evict cache for only a selected number of keys rather than evicting all entries:

```
@CacheEvict(value = BOOKS_CACHE, allEntries = true)
public int deleteByIds(final Collection<Long> booksIds) {
    // Delete all DB entries for given bookIds
}
```

I don't want to evict all entries but only who are in Collections.
Please suggest.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69829332/is-it-possible-to-cacheevict-keys-that-match-a-pattern) was asked in the past.

Essentially, if your keys follow a pattern, then with Redis in particular, you can use REGEX to match on keys for entries you wanted evicted from the Redis cache.

I never responded to this question specifically since the answer was adequate, and asked in the context of Redis. However, it did inspire me to generalize the solution a bit further in order to apply this technique beyond Redis.

If you are curious, you can have a look at the more generalized solution in this [test class](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithRegexIntegrationTests.java), which applies the given [Redis solution](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithRegexIntegrationTests.java#L307-L323) along with a [solution for Apache Geode](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithRegexIntegrationTests.java#L376-L406) and [1 last solution](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithRegexIntegrationTests.java#L276-L278) when a simple `ConcurrentMap` is used as the backing cache in *Spring's Cache Abstraction*.

Of course, the more generalized solution requires some extension(s) (beginning [here](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CacheEvictionWithRegexIntegrationTests.java#L411-L417)) to the core Spring Framework Cache Abstraction.

Anyway, hopefully this will give you some ideas how to cater these solutions to your use case. I am sure there are other possibilities as well.

Obviously, mileage will vary based on the caching provider (e.g. Redis) used with *Spring's Cache Abstraction* along with the requirements for your application use case.